# Is it possible to connect ldap server directly to Android phone?

Tags: java, android, linux, web-services, ldap

I need to get the contact list from the LDAP Server running on Linux.Is it there any android code or intent to access the ldap contents directly or we should only use the web services to access the ldap?I tried searching on the internet but no proper solution was found in any website.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/contactsinline/, https://github.com/weisserd/LDAP-Sync

Answer (score 2):

DanielWeisser already did that. The project is on GIT, you can modify source if you let the credentials. 
https://github.com/weisserd/LDAP-Sync

He used the [UnboundID LDAP Librairy](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/) to make this.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the LDAP client application https://market.android.com/details?id=com.unboundid.android.ldap.client&feature=search_result.  It provides the ability to do searches in an LDAP directory and access the results directly (e.g., dial phone numbers, send e-mail, map/navigate to addresses, etc.) as well as add them to your contacts.

Comment: Is there any code to access the ldap instead of the client app

Comment: You can use the UnboundID LDAP SDK for Java to write applications which run on Android.  That's what I used to write the LDAP client.