# installing LDAP sdk for java in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

Suggest me the procedure to install unbound LDAP sdk for java(eclipse) to run in android application.

Comment: how to install LDAP sdk in android for java

Comment: * [UnboundID LDAP SDK on android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704576/is-it-possible-to-connect-ldap-server-directly-to-android-phone)

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, all you have to do is right-click on your project, choose "Build Path" -> "Configure Build Path..." and then go to the "Libraries" tab. If you have the LDAP SDK jar somewhere in your workspace, then click "Add JARs..."; otherwise click "Add External JARs..." and then select the LDAP SDK jar.

Once this is done, you should see the unboundid-ldapsdk-se.jar in the list of jars on the classpath. While still in the "Configure Build Path..." window, if you click the arrow on the jar to expand it, you'll see that it let's you configure a "Source attachment". Click on this, hit "Edit..." and then select the src.zip that came with the LDAP SDK. This attaches the source (and the javadoc) so that it will show up automatically when you are programming with the LDAP SDK APIs.

Also, you may want to look at the [Minimal Edition](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/) of the LDAP SDK, which is a stripped-down version that still has all of the critical functionality but has some of the optional stuff left out to keep the jar file size down (and therefore the size of any application that uses it).